# How should I interpret a Chi-Squared Result?

Tags: astronomy, statistics

I've got a Model A with a reduced chi-square of 1.28.  I've got a Model B with a reduced chi-square of 0.70.  Which is a better model?  The model closest to 1 or the model closest to zero?

(Yes, I know this is probably better on the math site, but I got no answer there.  Besides, the chi-square is ubiquitous in astronomy and it would be useful to have a definitive answer so we can read the papers and understand the results)

Comment: Would this be better taken to [stats.se]? Most physicists have a rather hit-n-miss training in statistical methods and interpretation.

Comment: If most physicists have a poor training in statistical interpretation, don't you think it would be a good idea to fix that in the place they're most likely to look for information?

Comment: I didn't say they are bad at stats, I said they have a spotty understanding. They generally know the right or standard approaches to use in the problems they work on, but don't necessarily have a wide spread understanding.

Comment: You got no answer where?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The one closest to zero is the best fit, but depending on the conditions you can't rule out the model with 1.28. Most often you cannot rule out anything where Chi-squared is closer than 1 to the value of your best fit - but it does depend in reality on a bunch of things including the number of variables you used for your model fit, for example.

Numerical Recipes has a good description of Chi-squared fitting.

in response in comments....

0.7 and 1.28 are both reasonnably close to zero (and to 1) and the Chi-squared test indicates that *both* are reasonnable fits. --- if one fit gave 0.7 and another gave 325.6 then you could rule out the second model. Normally for 68% confidence we allow chi-squared to increase by 1, but here with several paramters we may need to increase by more than 1 - so here the Chi-squared test says that both are plausible fits to the data

Comment: A good fit and a good model are not the same thing. In particular you can always fit a dataset exactly with a high degree polynomial, but it generally won't have any physics content.

Comment: @dmckee - yes that is a very good point - Chi-squared only gives the best fit and does not judge on the correctness of the model. - I put 'correct' at first then editted to 'best fit'.

Comment: I don't want to 'rule any model out'.  I want to know which model is a better fit to the data.  Model A has three fitting parameters, Model B has two.  There are roughly 500 data points.  I want to draw a conclusion in my paper.  Is there a simple answer?

Comment: *"Model A has two fitting parameters, Model B has three. There are roughly 500 data points. Is there a simple answer?"* Either fit is defensible on that basic, but you should have included that data in your question.

Comment: So you're saying, what, exactly?  That below a certain point in the chi-square test there is no objective criteria for comparing one model to another?

Comment: @DonaldRoyAirey - 0.7 and 1.28 are both reasonnably close to zero (and to 1) and the Chi-squared test indicates that *both* are reasonnable fits. --- if one fit gave 0.7 and another gave 325.6 then you could rule out the second model. Normally for 68% confidence we allow chi-squared to increase by 1, but here with several paramters we may need to increase by more than 1 - so here the Chi-squared test says that both are plausible fits to the data

Comment: I'm not asking the question "are both of these plausible fits?", I'm asking the question "which is a better fit?".

Comment: @DonaldRoyAirey The better fit is 0.7, but the confidence that the 0.7 is the better fit is less than 68% so normally we would indicate that both are plausible fits because the betterness of the 0.7 may be due to experimental uncertainties for example

Comment: Model A is an established model.  No one will question that it's plausible.  Model B is the new kid on the block.  With one less fitting parameter and the exact same data set, am I on solid sound ground statistically to say that Model B is a better fit to the data than Model A or are there some additional qualifiers I need to provide?

Comment: @DonaldRoyAirey - just seeing your comment now. In my opinion you can say - Model B fits the data better than Model A. You can also say that Model B is preferable as it has one less fitting parameter. I am guessing that one less fitting parameter means less assumptions; if this is true then you can appeal to Occam's razor:
The principle can be interpreted as 'Among competing hypotheses, the one with the fewest assumptions should be selected' (quoted from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Occam's_razor  )

Comment: @tom Thanks for the additional information.  I have often been tempted to invoke Occam's Razor, but I understand from reading that it's a rule-of-thumb and can't be invoked as a proof.  Hopefully comparing reduced chi-square values will serve as a proof.  Let me know if I'm missing something.

Comment: @DonaldRoyAirey from my point of view 'proof' may be too strong a word - but I think you can state certainly that Model B is at least as good in practice as Model A and possibly better based on the Chi-squared .... and as a general principle myself and other scientist will prefer models with fewer fitting parameters, so I think you can suggest that Model B may be preferable as it has fewer fitting parameters.  To my mind in this sort of situation making modest claims that are rock solid may come over well.... hope this is helpful and best wishes for writing it up.